# Python PIL(Pillow): Convert a list of images into np.array efficiently?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I want to convert a list of images into np.array efficiently.

I have to process some jpg images read with `PIL.Image.open(img_path)`, and I have to process each one, after that I want to put them all into a list, and then convert it entirely into a `np.array` of the shape I want, `(N,H,W,C)`, which means `number of img`, `height`, `width`, `channel` respectively.

My trying:

```
all_img = []

for filename in all_filename_of_img[:100]:
    // process each img

    // then append each into the list
    all_img.append(img)

all_np_img = np.arrray(all_img, dtype=np.array)
```

with error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../playground.py", line 39, in <module>
    all_np_img = np.array(all_img, dtype=np.array)
TypeError: data type not understood
```

If I first convert each img inside the for loop by `img = np.asarray(img)` then do `all_img.append(img)`, would this be the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a numpy function called [`stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) that you can use in this case:

```
all_np_img = np.stack(all_img)
```

Comment: Wow this is very very efficient! I tried 1000 with old method and had to wait maybe a minute, but this just cost a blink...

Answer (score 0):

Use [np.vstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html):

```
pics = list()
for filename in all_filename_of_img[:100]:
    img = Image.open(filename)
    pics.append(img)

np.vstack(pics)
```